# Solr only index content whose text has a specified minimal length/size

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to import the allemanic wikipedia xml-dump. I specified some regex rules to ignore wikipedia pages like categories, files, templates, ... This configuration does work without any problems.

But then I wanted to restrict the indexing to documents that have a contents field with a length of at least 200 characters. But I cannot think of any way to do it. I tried some regex but then the indexing would always instantly fail (something like (.*){5} doesn't seem to be supported?).

Does anyone know a regex that is supported by solr to skip documents with only 200 or less characters? Or is there any other way to achive this behaviour?

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <document>
        <entity name="page" processor="XPathEntityProcessor" stream="true" forEach="/mediawiki/page/" url="/home/patrick/Desktop/alswiki-20130413-pages-articles.xml" transformer="RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer,HTMLStripTransformer,TemplateTransformer">
            <field column="origid" xpath="/mediawiki/page/id" />
            <field column="id" regex="^(.*)$" replaceWith="als-$1" sourceColName="origid" />
            <field column="name" xpath="/mediawiki/page/title" />
            <field column="revision_id" xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/id" />
            <field column="user"      xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/contributor/username" />
            <field column="contents" xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/text" stripHTML="true" />
            <field column="timestamp" xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/timestamp" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'" />
            <field column="source"  template="Swiss Wiki"/>
            <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^#REDIRECT.*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="contents"/>
            <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^#WEITERLEITUNG.*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="contents"/>
            <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^#Redirect.*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="contents"/>
            <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^Wikipedia:.*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="name"/>
            <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^MediaWiki:.*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="name"/>
            <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^Vorlage:.*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="name"/>
            <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^Datei:.*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="name"/>
            <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^Hilfe:.*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="name"/>
            <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^Portal:.*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="name"/>
            <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^Kategorie:.*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="name"/>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `(.*){5}` will match exactly 5 characters. `(.*){5,}` will match five or more. So for 200, it would be `(.*){200,}`.

If this doesn't work, it is reasonably easy to write a custom transformer:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHCustomTransformer